# What is the keyboard short cut for listing active files in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: editor, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Like something on Aptana (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>). So switching between the files would be easy.

Comment: I don't use Aptana, could you at least explain better what you mean by switching between the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last, I figured it out by using manual brute forcing ;) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

Comment: That doesn't just show active files, but it the Open Any command (which is probably better anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Try the [GotoOpenFile plugin](https://github.com/phildopus/sublime-goto-open-file), you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to show all active files.